# Is the price of flights Anchorage (ANC) - Wales (WAA) always the same?

Tags: usa, air-travel, price, alaska, alaska-airlines

According to Google Flights, the price of cheapest roundtrip flights ANC-WAA is always $794, except a few isolated cases when it's in the $800-900 range. I was wondering whether this even goes down, or whether it is fixed?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all fares published for a route using tools like [ExpertFlyer](https://www.expertflyer.com/) or [KVS Availability Tool](http://www.kvstool.com/), and use the same to check inventory. Both services require a subscription.

The first data point lets you know what the range of possible fares is—if the lowest fare filed plus taxes and fees is $700, it is impossible for you to do any better than $700. The second data point lets you know how many seats are available for purchase at a given fare. The cheapest posted fare might be $25, but if inventory is set to zero through the end of the schedule, you'd never be able to buy it.

---

In general, waiting for cheaper seats to be released is a gamble, and we usually counsel people to book as soon as they find a fare they are comfortable paying. Too many people hold out hoping the fare will dip $50 only to have it go up $75.

There are very few available seats to WAA. The choice is down to RavnAir Connect and Bering Air, both operating Piper or Cessna light aircraft, and both requiring a connection at Nome (OME) plus up to two additional stops. With such little demand and such little competition, the airlines have no incentive to offer substantial discounts—it's the height of summer travel and based on the [BCD Travel](https://flightavailability.bcdtravel.com/) tool, it seems all flights tomorrow (July 23) are still wide open.